# Looping Array Based on Variable

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I need to create a specific array (which I am using in a series) based on a variable Y.  This is the format I am using - trying to do it in VBScript.

```
If Y=2 then

    S1 = [0,x]
    S2 = [x,0]

If Y=3 then

    S1 = [0,0,x]
    S2 = [0,x,0]
    S3 = [x,0,0]

If Y=4 then

    S1 = [0,0,0,x]<br/>
    S2 = [0,0,x,0]<br/>
    S3 = [0,x,0,0]<br/>
    S4 = [x,0,0,0]<br/>

If Y=5 then

    S1 = [0,0,0,0,x]
    S2 = [0,0,0,x,0]
    S3 = [0,0,x,0,0]
    S4 = [0,x,0,0,0]
    S5 = [x,0,0,0,0]
```

etc etc.  I know it is going to be a for loop -------------

```
for i = 1 to Y
    S[i] = "[.... this is where am drawing a brain freeze
next
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this SQL?  Is this SQL or VB?  And what is `[0,0,0,0,x]`?  Is it a single string or an array of 5 items?

Comment: Snippet: `ReDim s(1 To y, 1 To y)
For i = 1 To y
    s(i, y - i + 1) = x
Next
`

Comment: i tagged sql, becasue I am grabbing the variable from there. vb is the script I am writing in.  sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Daniel - i couldn't get the redim to produce what i was looking for.. how would i apply that?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Redim` statement as delivered by Daniel Cook does not work that way in VBScript, only in VB or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arraylists to dynamically create your arrays and transfer them back to a vbscript array to make it accessable for other functions. (Or you can just keep using the arraylists that, in my opinion, are superior to normal arrays.)

```
Option Explicit

' Initialize
Dim x : x = "X"
Dim Y : Y = 5
Dim AL : Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim i, j, innerAL, S

' Make a loop to iterate over the amount of array entries we have to create
for i = 1 to Y

    ' This arraylist is used to set the inner array
    Set innerAL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 

    ' Fill the inner array
    for j = 0 to Y-1

        ' See if it has to be filled with X or 0
        If j = (Y-i) then
            innerAL.Add x
        else
            innerAL.Add 0
        end if
    next

    ' Convert the inner arraylist to a standard array and add it to the outer arraylist
    AL.Add innerAL.ToArray()

next

' We are done. Convert the arraylist to a standard array
S = AL.ToArray()

' Display the results
for i = 0 to Y-1
    wscript.echo "S(" & i & ") = [" & join(S(i), ",") & "]"
Next
```